# Extract fractions numbers from text and sum - odd results?

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, fractions, google-query-language

I have a cell containing fractions as text, like:

`2/4 + 2/4 +2/4`

I want to extract fractions as numbers, and sum them.

I tried a simple:

```
=SPLIT(A2, "+")
```

that correctly split numbers in three columns

and then

```
=SUM(SPLIT(A2, "+"))
```

but got this wrong result:

```
4/19
```

Can you help understand how to get right result?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(, "select "&A2), 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you discover this on your own? Or is it something you picked up elsewhere? Either way, it's new to me and a "keeper" for sure. So thanks for teaching me something new today.

Comment: Hu? Something new is going on here. How does `Query`command work in this context ?  I see it translates a text into a formula and no cell range is given: I have not found examples about it. And I see `index` used to return the content of a cell, that in this examples resolve the formula "extracted" by the query command. Could you illustrate handy use cases of query and index commands ? Any reference and examples to learn from ? (Generally Query are given with examples of ranges and SQL, have not found this). I mark it up as correct answer for sure, thank you if wish to come back and comment!

Comment: P.S. Could you anyway clarify why the commands in my question produced unexpected results ? I checked further : it seems fractions are extracted by the split command properly, as "2/4", but they are interpreted as different numbers (`VALUE(SPLIT(A2, "+"))` returns `44231`, not `0.5`). I cannot figure out how dividend operator is interpreted to yield this result.

Comment: A text string like `2/4` looks like a date and gets converted to a dateserial number when `split()` is used. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.

Comment: P.S. #2 - :) I would like to "map" the function to all cells in the column containing the fractions. I wish to do it with an `Arrayformula`but it is not dynamically filling the column (while it works if dragging the cells). Could you tell how `Arrayformula`should be used in this context ? I tried to give range like this `=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(QUERY(, "select "&A2 : A), 2))` but it only return value for cell `A2`

Comment: @ErikTyler no idea if I am first :) but to my knowledge, only QUERY can do this kind of job so it's either this short solution or a long one with regex replacing of all numbers with `Col1,Col2,Col3,etc` references, splitting it on each math symbol, and use it as 2nd query argument while first query argument will have the split cell as a range in array brackets {} and then removing the header/label to get the result only

Comment: @user305883 see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dA5Wh8_sKPZlJm9otJquuLCBd1X8Oa5ZdcJ1oJ8vH8k/edit#gid=743751824 as for why you getting unexpected results, @@doubleunary is right. value 44231 is a date in its numeric format

Comment: @user305883 for arrayformula you can try: `=FLATTEN(INDEX(QUERY(, "select "&JOIN(",", A1:A3)), 2))` see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dA5Wh8_sKPZlJm9otJquuLCBd1X8Oa5ZdcJ1oJ8vH8k/edit#gid=92677023